# How to make a actual 'collision' but not let them moving through with each other

Tags: libgdx, collision

I've made two rectangles for the objects, the .overflap() does work well, but the problem is the objects are going to get through with each other after the collision, and each frame it will return a detected collision message. How to solve this problem it drives me crazy:(

Answer (score 0):

1) Box2D
2) Something like this (from Learning Libgdx Game Development)

```
private void onCollisonBunnyHeadWithRock(Rock rock) {
        BunnyHead bunnyHead = level.bunnyHead;
        float heightDifference = Math.abs(bunnyHead.position.y
                - (rock.position.y + rock.bounds.height));
        if (heightDifference > 0.25f) {
            boolean hitLeftEdge = bunnyHead.position.x > (rock.position.x + rock.bounds.width / 2.0f);
            if (hitLeftEdge) {
                bunnyHead.position.x = rock.position.x + rock.bounds.width;
            } else {
                bunnyHead.position.x = rock.position.x - bunnyHead.bounds.width;
            }
            return;
        }
        switch (bunnyHead.jumpState) {
        case GROUNDED:
            break;
        case FALLING:
        case JUMP_FALLING:
            bunnyHead.position.y = rock.position.y + bunnyHead.bounds.height
                    + bunnyHead.origin.y;
            bunnyHead.jumpState = JUMP_STATE.GROUNDED;
            break;
        case JUMP_RISING:
            bunnyHead.position.y = rock.position.y + bunnyHead.bounds.height
                    + bunnyHead.origin.y;
            break;
        }
    }
```